# Angular: Global Error Handler working only once

Tags: angular

I have a service which calls a REST API. The `create` operation POST the parameters, and then GET the created object by using the `id` returned in the HTTP header. When the object is returned, a Subject propagates the object to notify other components. You can notice that I don't call the `catch` operation. I did it on purpose so the global error handler manages the error It works as expected the first time, but the second time, the global error handler is not called.

In the Chrome console, I get an error after the first call but not after the second call in `rxjs/Subscriber.js`:

```
Subscriber.js:240 Uncaught 
Response {_body: "{"message":"The query is not valid"}", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}

SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub = function (fn, value) {
        try {
            fn.call(this._context, value);
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.unsubscribe();
            throw err;
        }
    };
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SystemService {

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  create(system: SdqlSystem) {
    this.http.post(environment.apiEndpoint + 'systems', system)
      .flatMap(res => {
        const location = res.headers.get('Location');
        return this.http.get(location);
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => this.subject.next(data));

  }

  get(id: string) {
    this.http.get(environment.apiEndpoint + 'systems/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => this.subject.next(data));
  }

  systems(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

The call from a form:

```
onSubmit({value, valid}: { value: SdqlSystem, valid: boolean }) {
  this.systemService.create(value);
}
```

The global error handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private logger: LoggingService, private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
  }

  handleError(error: Response | any): void {
    console.log('***** HANDLE ERROR *****');
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || body.message || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    this.logger.error(errMsg);
    this.notificationsService.error('Error', errMsg);
    throw error;
  }

}
```

Comment: Since you re-throw in your `GlobalErrorHandler`, don't provide an `onError`-function in your subscribe and don't catch the error anywhere else you are in an 'uncaught exception-state' where the browser stops execution. What do you want to happen? I'm afraid you have to catch the error somewhere in your pipeline if you want execution to continue. Is your question, *why* you get a chrome error in the first place? (I can answer that, but I'm not sure if that's really your question)

Comment: As you mentioned, the error is to rethrow in the `GlobalErrorHandler`. Removing it fix the issue. Make it an answer if you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OP already resolved it, but I guess I'll answer in case someone else stumbles upon this problem:

Rethrowing the error in the `GlobalErrorHandler` leads to an uncaught exception where the browser stops execution. That's why it works only once.
**The solution is simply to not rethrow in the ErrorHandler.**

More detail: In this case there is no `onError`-function provided in `subscribe()`. That's why `rxjs/Subscriber.js` runs into the `catch`-part of `__tryOrUnsub`.
It tries to execute the `onError`-function but fails (because there is none) and therefore unsubscribes from the Observable and throws the error.
The `GlobalErrorHandler` picks it up, does logging and notification and then rethrows it.
At this point the error becomes an uncaught exception outside of Angular.
(*the default [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) does not rethrow an error*)

**Note:** this approach works for standard http-calls, because the Response-Observable only emits one value and then completes anyway.
If you have an Observable that needs to emit more than one value you will have to deal with the error differently because an Observable that emits an error will not emit any further values, as specified in the [Observable-Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html):

> **OnError**
>     indicates that the Observable has terminated with a specified error condition and that **it will be emitting no further items**

Comment: After spending hours to check why multiple exceptions are not getting logged if I implemented the custom ErrorHandler in Angular, I found this answer really helpful and it simply solved my issue just by commenting `throw error` at the end of custom error handler function.